# Single sign-on toolbar for multiple projects, MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on

I am building a set of services based on MVC 4. They should all be a part of the same authentication system. Currently I have got a separate project for all the model handling, including the Forms Authentication you get by default when making a new MVC 4 app.

Now, I would like to make a toolbar for logging in to our cloud services, and this toolbar must be made in such a way that it can be imported into our other services. Logging in with this toolbar should log you in to all our services, that are separated into different MVC apps. Thus logging in when browsing "service1" and then going to "service2", you should still be logged in with the same user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Should I make a separate MVC app for this toolbar, and somehow reference it in all of my other projects? Should I export my controllers into a separate project and use them? I am not sure what the best practice is here, nor where to find the info I need on the matter.

Comment: Will those *services/applications* be hosted on the same root domain (i.e. `service1.foo.com`, `service2.foo.com`, ...) or will they be on separate domains (`service1.com`, `service2.com`, ...)?

Comment: They will use the same database, but have different domains.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be hosting your applications on different domains, you could implement some Single Sign On mechanism the way SO does it over the Stack Exchange network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274

Answer (score 0):

Different domains means that you won't be able to share the Forms cookie. You should rather learn how to use one of the enterprise Single Sign-on protocols - using a recognized protocol means that you can easily integrate other applications, even if they are developed in different technologies (standarized protocols are supported by most development environments).

Possible candidates are:

- the OAuth2 protocol. It is a respected protocol as Google, LiveID, Facebook, Twitter and others support it. To build an OAuth2 server you will need a framework like the DotNetOpenAuth.
- WS-Federation. Got a lot of attention in .NET world as we got the Windows Identity Foundation framework which lets you create WS-Federation servers and clients.

Anyway, my advice is to invest your time now as this will pay off well in future.